# apache service can't be start

Tags: apache, virtualhost, lamp

Things weird:

- 1:I compiled this LAMP environment with
  ***`./configure --enable-layout=RedHat  --enable-so --enable-mods-shared=all --with-ldap  --enable-ldap  -enable-authnz-ldap --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl --enable-ssl && make && make install`***
- 2: This configured for name based virtualhost with SSL(not for a
  single virtualhost)
- 3: I can start the apache service with default website, but can't
  start when i config the virtualhost
- 4: with testing too many times, I found i can start the apache
  service with default website first, then modify the http.conf file to
  uncomment virtualhost config line, and exec command "apachectl -k
  restart", finally the virtualhost will be up.
- 5: I can't find any error messages from apache error log, It just
  show:

> [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
>
> [crit] (4)Interrupted system call: Digest: error generating secret: Interrupted system call Configuration Failed
>
> [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `*.example.com' does NOT match server name!?
>
> [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `*.example.com' does NOT match server name!?
>
> [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `*.example.com' does NOT match server name!?
>
> [warn] Init: SSL server IP/port conflict: china.example.com:443 (/etc/httpd/conf.d/china.conf:49) vs. hk.example.com:443 (/etc/httpd/conf.d/hk.conf:45)
>
> [warn] Init: SSL server IP/port conflict: korea.tkeexample.com:443 (/etc/httpd/conf.d/korea.conf:45) vs. hk.example.com:443 (/etc/httpd/conf.d/hk.conf:45)
>   [warn] Init: You should not use name-based virtual hosts in conjunction with SSL!!

- 6: I know there are config mistake, but how can I find it, cause i
  know there is not place to find out error from virtualhost
  configuration.

Comment: Does apache fail to start? or can you just not see your website?

Comment: hey man, I just found the root cause, but I can't explain y, In my ssl.conf file, I changed "Listen 433" to "Listen 0.0.0.0:433", then the service can startup, I really confused about this phenomenon.

Comment: Ok, well, try change that to `Listen 443`  as 443 is the correct port.